# NumPy mathematical functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get the first digit of an integer in a NumPy 1D array so I can perform some statistical analysis on the resulting 1D array.

How would I perform the following function in NumPy (i.e. using the NumPy mathematical functions)?

---

```
import math

number = 23456

firstNumber = number // 10 ** int(math.log(number, 10))
```

---

How do I apply the above function to a 1D NumPy array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: use `numpy` instead of `math`?

Comment: keen to apply this to a 1D array - which I assume is possible?

Comment: *"I am trying to get the first digit of an integer in a NumPy 1D array"* That sounds pretty clear to me; I don't understand why this was closed as "unclear".   There is even code that does what was asked, but for a Python integer instead of a numpy array.  @Julien's comment might be flippant, but an answer that shows *how* to use numpy to do this sounds like it would be a fine answer.

Comment: @Algorithm, you can write the expression in a form that is even closer to your Python code.  Suppose `n = np.array([2, 456, 23456, 990])`.  Then `first = n // 10**np.log10(n).astype(int)` should give you what you want.

Comment: It worked, thanks again @WarrenWeckesser - greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Algorithm Be aware that that formula assumes the integers are all greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
number // 10 ** np.log10(number).astype(int)
```